# Any way to control the Quad LED individually in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift

iPhones now have four LEDs to produce the flash light.

I want to programatically turn each LED on or off to produce different light effects, or even just specify the balance between pink LEDs and white leds.

Any way to have a tighter control on those in swift ?

Digging the API didn't show much...

Thanks !!